# How to create multiple charts group by month for each category in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to display multiple charts, one for each category, the chart which is grouped by a variable ( month ) to compare 2 columns, total number and unique number of counts.

I tried matplotlib but no help.

Also, I wonder if I can loop through a dataframe filter by I worry each chart would get overridden by latest chart.

```
data = {'category': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charles', 'David', 'Eric'],
        'Month': ['Jan','Feb','March','April'],
        'Total': [40000, 24000, 31000, 20000, 30000], 
        'unique': [6000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 3000]}
```

Please view my desired view of charts below. ( Just a sample I created in MS Paint )

[image: https://imgur.com/a/fTcaXxn]

So all in all, for 5 categories, I want to create 5 charts, grouped by each month for total counts and unique counts.

Comment: shouldn't your sample data have several months for each 'category'?

Comment: My original data spans only 5 months, but i wanted a generic solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After even more reasearch,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a grid : initialize it
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='Brand_Name', hue='Brand_Name', col_wrap=4, )

# Add the line over the area with the plot function
g = g.map(plt.plot, 'Month', 'Count_of_HCP_Visited')

# Fill the area with fill_between
g = g.map(plt.fill_between,'Month', 'Count_of_Unique_HCP_Visited', alpha=0.2).set_titles("{col_name}")

# Control the title of each facet
g = g.set_titles("{col_name}")

# Add a title for the whole plo
plt.subplots_adjust(top=1.0)
#g = g.fig.suptitle('Evolution of the value of stuff in 16 countries')

plt.show()
```

[Click here for link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfhag.png)